# How to print special characters in a loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to print the following pattern:

```
@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@
@@@@@@
@@@@@
```

However, I am getting this instead:

```
@ABCDEFG
ABCDEFG
BCDEFG
CDEFG
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate any feedback or direction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 4
#define CHARS 8

int main(void)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for(char ch = ('@' + row); ch < ('@' + CHARS); ch++)
            printf("%c", ch);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: I'm using a text editor, and so it doesn't have a debugger.

Comment: What do you think `'@' + row`  does?

Comment: regardless of which text editor you used, to compile obviously you have to use a compiler, which will most probably have a debugger alongside

Comment: @DDKGM Get an free IDE with a good compiler / debugger - there are several for every platform. You cannot learn to write code without learning debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` operator doesn't work the way you think it does. `@` is converted to it's ASCII value (64) then you add `row`. When `row` is `2`, you are saying: print the character that coresponds the number (64 + 2) which is `A`.

[Here's an ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

I would change the inside loop to something like this:

```
for(int ch = row; ch < CHARS; ch++) {
    printf("%c", '@');
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 5):

Why are you complicating second `for` with that character. It can be simply

```
for(int col = row; col < CHARS; col++)
    printf("%c", '@');
```

Comment: Or `printf("@");` or even `putchar('@');` The `%c` conversion is pointless when the character being printed is a constant.

Comment: @user3386109 I just doesn't need to confuse the questioner with new function `putchar` but it is of course great alternative. On the other hand, I consider `printf("@")` potentially unsafe. He can change his mind and change the character from `@` to `%` and he will be lost.

Comment: @user3386109 A good compiler will generate the same code for `printf("%c", '@');`, `printf("@");`, `putchar('@');`.  Best to use what makes sense for the context of the larger code and let the compiler handle these small optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ch to '@'
`printf("%c", '@');`